# Illegal memory accessed while using double pointer in CUDA

Tags: pointers, cuda, nvidia

In the code given below, **d_slot** is a double pointer initialized to **NULL** in the main.
It's value is changed in the kernel '**test**'. 
The code which i'm going to implement requires the value of **d_slot** to be carried and *not be reverted back to **NULL*** as it happens after '**test**' is completed.
(This is perhaps because the double pointer is passed by value and not by reference)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_profiler_api.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct radix_tree_root {
    unsigned int        height;
    struct radix_tree_node  *rnode;
};

struct radix_tree_node {
    unsigned int    count;
    void        *slots[64];
};

__global__ void test1(struct radix_tree_node **d_slot,struct radix_tree_root *d_root)
{
    (d_slot) = &d_root->rnode;
    printf("From test1: d_slot = %p\t*d_slot = %p\n",d_slot,*d_slot);
}

__global__ void test2(struct radix_tree_node **d_slot)
{
    printf("From test2: d_slot = %p\n",d_slot);
}

__global__ void test3(struct radix_tree_node ***d_slot,struct radix_tree_root *d_root)
{
    (*d_slot) = &d_root->rnode;
}


int
main(void)
{
    struct radix_tree_root *root,*d_root;
    struct radix_tree_node **d_slot=NULL;
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
    root = (struct radix_tree_root *) malloc(sizeof(struct radix_tree_root));
    root->height = 0;
    root->rnode =NULL;


    //allocate memory to d_root in the GPU//
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_root, sizeof(struct radix_tree_root));
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device d_root (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //copy root to d_root
    err = cudaMemcpy(d_root, root, (sizeof(struct radix_tree_root)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy root from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    printf("\nFrom the main: d_root = %p\n",d_root);
    test1<<<1,1>>>(d_slot,d_root);
    err = cudaGetLastError();//brief Returns the last error from a runtime call
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    test2<<<1,1>>>(d_slot);
    err = cudaGetLastError();//brief Returns the last error from a runtime call
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //test3<<<1,1>>>(&d_slot,d_root);
    err = cudaGetLastError();//brief Returns the last error from a runtime call
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //test2<<<1,1>>>(d_slot);
    err = cudaGetLastError();//brief Returns the last error from a runtime call
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    err = cudaFree(d_root);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device d_root (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    free(root);

    printf("successful execution of entire program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
From the main: d_root = 0x900ca0000
From test1: d_slot = 0x900ca0008    *d_slot = (nil)
From test2: d_slot = (nil)
successful execution of entire program
```

This was all fine. But when i uncommented the '**test3**' and the '**test2**' kernels given in the above code,
I expected the value of **d_slot** to be carried forward...
However, there was an error encountered...

The output of the code with '**test3**' and '**test2**' uncommented is:

```
From the main: d_root = 0x900ca0000
From test1: d_slot = 0x900ca0008    *d_slot = (nil)
From test2: d_slot = (nil)
Failed to free device d_root (error code an illegal memory access was encountered)!
```

So my question is,

*"How do I successfully assign value to d_slot (a double pointer)
in the kernel without losing it's value after the the completion of kernel-execution?"*

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be some location in graphics memory that `test1` can write to and `test2` and `test3` can read from.  You could use `cudaMalloc` a second time to allocate space for a `struct radix_tree_node *` like so:

```
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_slot, sizeof(struct radix_tree_root *));
```

Then `test1` can write a pointer value to `*d_slot` and `test2` and `test3` can read the value that `test1` wrote from `*d_slot`.